# OSError setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1 when setting up pipenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Seems to be out of the blue, but I am unable to setup pipenv's on my ubuntu machine.

I have tried reinstalling virtualenv and upgrading pip.

```
✘ Failed creating virtual environment 
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "/home/rob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 390, in shell
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       pypi_mirror=state.pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "/home/rob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2156, in do_shell
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       three=three, python=python, validate=False, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "/home/rob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 574, in ensure_project
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "/home/rob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 506, in ensure_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       python=python, site_packages=site_packages, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "/home/rob/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 935, in do_create_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       extra= 
[crayons.blue("{0}".format(c.err)),]
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2632, in <module>
main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 870, in main
symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1173, in create_environment
install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1019, in install_wheel
_install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1110, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=script)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 963, in call_subprocess
raise OSError("Command {} failed with error code {}".format(cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/rob/.local/sha...mMwzlaYo/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Really not sure what's happened here.  I've been through the other answers on SO, but they seem to be appropriate for other packages.

Thanks!

Comment: Also seen i'm getting this :
    WARNING: The directory '/home/rob/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: It's trying to run a command like `python3 - setuptools pip wheel` which does not look like a valid command. What did you type in?